# dsp book with matlab

Tags: matlab

Hi All: I was thinking about buying a "DSP book with matlab". I'm not sure which one is generally recommended  but that's not my question. My question is, when you buy such a book, do they require the DSP toolbox (assuming it exists) or just the regular base matlab. I have the base matlab but I would think the  toolboxes are pretty expensive so I don't want to buy a book only to find out that I need  the dsp toolbox. Or if the answer is that there is no such toolbox, that's fine also. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use octave? You get all the toolboxes for free, and you have almost all functions that Matlab has. If you're getting serious with signal processing you will definitely need the signal processing toolbox.

Comment: Yeah, Matlab itself is just a pretty terrible programming language, the niceness really is in the libraries! Sure, even base Matlab is *huge* and comes with an extensively documented library. But, honestly, you won't learn much if you learn "matlab programming" from a book. Matlab programming a) isn't a very rich, complex or beautiful tool, and b) is not what you'd usually strive to learn – learn enough matlab to solve problems (use the free tutorials that come with matlab). Learn DSP algorithms separately from that.

Comment: Now comes the slightly grumpy part: whenever you look at the really cool algorithms available pre-made in matlab, easily half of them are implemented in C/C++ and wrapped for matlab. The reason is simply that .m is such an inefficiently designed language that you can't really write halfway performant core algorithms. It's very much good enough (and millions of research project prove that!) to *use* these algorithms. Does it make sense to learn how to implement these algorithms themselves in Matlab? Not more than in any other language...

Comment: So: learn Matlab programming by the tutorials, and get a good DSP textbook, or watch good DSP lectures (I'd like to recommend MIT's opencourseware courses) and occasionally ask yourself how you'd implement that and then go ahead and implement it.

Comment: [Just to put this into perspective: I work at a communications engineering / software defined radio university institute. We haven't really used Matlab in 90% of student theses over the last ~7 years; most was Python, and when it came to performance, C++. We have started using it more in the last year – because we've gotten a channel coding focus, and the communications toolbox comes with reference implementation for certain types of decoders, which we intend to beat the hell out of ;) . So basically, we're mainly using Matlab for reference. Matlab without comms toolbox would be useless to us]

Comment: that was all very useful. I think I'll nix that idea of using matlab and, when I do decide to work on that,  I'll go with octave or R or Python. thanks to everyone for comments.